# Does Lightbox for jQuery write a div into the DOM or simply show a hidden div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, lightbox

I have a very specific question about the lightbox plugin for jQuery. Does it write a div into the DOM dynamically, or does it simply show a hidden div?

Comment: how hard is this to figure out by inspecting the DOM in browser dev tools? hit F12 and take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the div is created when Lightbox is instantiated (build function), and the div is simply shown when start() is called.

Source: https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/master/src/js/lightbox.js